# Regex to match "maybe valid month"

Tags: javascript, regex, date

Basically I want to match the following:

```
const regex = /(?=.*[0-1])(?=.*[^0{2}])|(0[1-9]|1[012])$/
console.log('0, should be True: ', regex.test('0'))
console.log('1, should be True: ', regex.test('1'))
console.log('00, should be False: ', regex.test('00'))
console.log('01, should be True: ', regex.test('01'))
console.log('12, should be True: ', regex.test('12'))
console.log('99, should be False: ', regex.test('99'))
```

Valid: `0, 1, 01-09, 10-12`
Invalid: `00, >12`

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: `^\d{0,1}$` "4 more to go"

Comment: Is there a reason why you cannot use a datepicker instead of manually validating that with a regex?

Comment: Why is 0 valid if the month is 1-12?

Comment: @wirap because it's "as-you-type". So the valid numbers are "maybe valid" vs "completely valid"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do:

```
const regex = /^([01]|0[1-9]|1[012])$/;
```

That is, either of:

- Single digit 0 or 1
- 0 followed by single digit 1 .. 9
- 1 followed by 0, 1 or 2

Output of your tests:

> ```
> 0, should be True:  true
> 1, should be True:  true
> 00, should be False:  false
> 01, should be True:  true
> 12, should be True:  true
> 99, should be False:  false
> ```

Answer (score 0):

This will do:

```
/^0[1-9]|[0-9]|1[0-2]$/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
var regex = /^\d?$|^0[1-9]?$|^1(=?[0-2])$/;
```

or:

```
var regex = /^\d?$|^0[1-9]?$|^1[0-2]$/;
```

or:

```
var regex = /^(\d?|^0[1-9]?|^1[0-2])$/;
```

there are many possible way you can achieve the same results.